# Getting "invalid credentials" error when using people picker on google+ interactive post widget

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-api, google-plus

I've embedded the interactive post widget on my page. When clicking on the "people picker" within the interactive post, to directly select some friends to post to, I get the following error:

> Invalid credentials (missing or invalid oAuth token)

Anyone experiencing the same error?
Please advise.

Thanks and best,
Julian

Comment: Here is a non-working example:n http://www.wagnerwebconsult.de/gplustest.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong here - I think the bug is with the people chooser itself.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I've been afraid of :-/